# Bootstraping chef client on the node itself

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to write a script that will run during the boot process and installs the chef client. The validation.pem and client.rb files are placed in the /etc/chef folder, the validation.pem here is taken from the chef server and is the organization-validation.pem file. I have created an image of this VM and using to create another VM. This script run chef-client and for some reason I get this:

```
Creating a new client identity for node1 using the validator key.
[2015-08-06T19:52:16+00:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host:     xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Running handlers:
[2015-08-06T19:52:16+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-08-06T19:52:16+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 2.966424961 seconds
[2015-08-06T19:52:16+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-    
stacktrace.out
[2015-08-06T19:52:16+00:00] ERROR: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3     
read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
[2015-08-06T19:52:16+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Also, I cannot really make use of Knife as its not configured as chef client is not installed to begin with. Am I using wrong certificate? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using a self-signed SSL certificate. Since Chef 12, Chef does not trust these certificates anymore.

You can add `ssl_verify_mode :verify_none` to your client.rb, just to check if that works.

The proper way to fix this problem is to add the certificate to `/etc/chef/trusted_certs`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. what certificate should be added to /etc/chef/trusted_certs?

Comment: I tried to do what you said, but I still get some error which makes no sense to me now:Generated at 2015-08-06 20:20:23 +0000
OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: nested asn1 error
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/http/ssl_policies.rb:81:in `each'
----
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:382:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:55:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:55:in `<main>'

Comment: Did you sign the certificate? What were the exacts steps in the creation of the certificate?

Comment: The certificate that I am using is the organization-validation certificate that is created when creating the admin user on the chef server.

Comment: You should be able to find the correct certificate in `/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/HOSTNAME.crt`. Can you please try that?

Comment: Ok, I placed that cert onto the node, and get this error:Authentication Error:
---------------------
Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).

Server Response:
----------------
Failed to authenticate as 'validation'. Ensure that your node_name and client key are correct.

Relevant Config Settings:
-------------------------
chef_server_url         "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443/organizations/xxxx"
validation_client_name  "validation"
validation_key          "/etc/chef/validation.pem"

If these settings are correct, your validation_key may be invalid.

Comment: this is my client.rb :
log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443/organizations/xxxx"
validation_client_name "validation"
validation_key "/etc/chef/validation.pem"
node_name "node1"
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none
trusted_certs_dir "/etc/chef/trusted_certs"
~

Comment: That's good, different error means we fixed the first problem. If you already have an /etc/chef/client.pem, delete it. It looks like your validation.pem is incorrect - are you sure it's the correct file?

Comment: Nope, I don't have the client.pem file. 
Yes, I cross verified that, my organization-validation.pem and this validation.pem file are same

Comment: `validation_client_name` in client.rb should probably be "ORGANIZATION-validator". If that doesn't work, I'm sorry, I don't know what to do, you might want to regenerate all validation certs and start over.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your time and help. I will keep trying.